# jboss taking and executing old ear instead of a new deployed one

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, ear

i'm using JBoss 5.1.0.GA on a linux machine and i'm deploying an ear for an EJB project, while looking at the server logs, i undeploy the old ear and it undeploys successfully then i put my new ear in the deploy directory and also the logs show that it is deployed successfully but when running the project, the new changes don't take effect and the old ear content gets executed instead. please advise!

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem with 5.1 EJB3 projects on a windows machine a couple of times. Something very fishy going on.

have you tried everything?

i.e. undeploy, stop the service, restart the machine if possible, start the service, re-deploy

i remember in my case it stuck until the machine was restarted. never actually found the problem though.

Comment: it works when i remove the old ear, restart jboss and then deploy the new one but it doesnt make sense because it's not a hot deployment anymore. you're right it's weird and i think it has something to do with the temp folder where jboss explores the ear and war files.

Comment: yes, i only had this problem twice that i can remember, and we do a lot of hot deployments using .ear's so it should be quite rare. I think the normal deployment should work again if you've restarted the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

After shutting down the server, just delete all of the temporary folders that get generated when JBoss starts. Those folders are (if you use default folder):

- /server/default/data
- /server/default/log
- /server/default/tmp
- /server/default/work

After deleting them, just restart JBoss and all your new changes should be there.